# Cannot change GeoNetwork record view user interface

Tags: geonetwork

I have GeoNetwork (v 4.2.4) and I want to make some simple changes to the default metadata record view. I made the installation with docker.

I looked at or tried:

1. [Change GeoNetwork default metadata view](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202539) but version 4.2.4 differs significativelly from version 3.0.4. For example, the file /WEB-INF/config-lucene.xml doesn't exist anymore or is not called the same.
2. [Remove bounding box from metadata view in Geonetwork](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413821) and change the file "recordView.html" but still no change. Like it doesn't affect the UI at all.
3. The documentation says that you can change the formatter in Metadata and templates >> Formatter. I tried to edit them but still no change.

Is there a default formatter somewhere?

Optionally, I want to modify the advanced view (which is more complete than the default view) and put this view by default when entering the page.